# Java: can db4o store org.w3c.dom.Node?

Tags: java, dom, db4o

Is it possible to store `org.w3c.dom.Node` and `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` as well?

```
public DocumentElement {
private String name;
private Node thisNode;
private NodeList thisList;
}
```

If not, is it possible to serialize `Node` or `NodeList` into `JSON` or `String` for db4o storage?

is there a list of supported data types for persistence with db4o? I couldn't find it on the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Nodes only make sense within the context of their Document. But what you can do is generate a representation of the document in a string and store that. (I do that when I have to store XML in a database, except I store it after compressing it; that's OK for my application, because it's not a field that the DB has to be able to look inside.)

Comment: Yep. Maybe storing and loading even works. However since you don't have control over the w3c-dom implementation you cannot predict if you can load it again with another version of the library. You you should create your own Node representation and store that.

Comment: DOM is pretty much specified in such a way that you can only serialize whole documents (in particular, you can ask a node for its parent node). Storing a document _is_ well-defined (it's really just a funny string). You can make new documents with copies of some set of nodes too; that's a pretty standard XML manipulation.

Comment: Well of course db4o would store referenced document as well (if it works at all). Anyway, its a bad idea to store it directly.